# Short story collection with one story where two boys saw the arm off a statue that is holding gold-painted torch

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

About 20-25 years ago, when I was a kid, I picked up a short story collection in a Waldenbooks store (I believe it was a collection of stories, however it is possible that this was just a novella). The story that I remember featured two adolescent boys who steal a gold-painted torch from a statue in a fountain on a playground. they saw the arm off the statue, and flee from the scene via a drainage pipe. I believe they're tailed by some sort of monster, and I think they use some kind of mortar they found to attack the monster.

The story stuck with me. Any clues?

Comment: Sounds very interesting! Any idea what time period it was set in? Was it set in the real world or a fantasy world?